# Dart: Is jsonEncode completely predictable?

Tags: json, dart

I was wondering if the function `jsonEncode()` from the `dart:convert` library is entirely predictable. That is, will `jsonEncode()` always encode the keys and values of a `Map` object in the same order?

Comment: Map objects are unordered. They can appear in JSON in any order, and will be parsed identically no matter what the order is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: it depends.

Maps as a general rule don't store any order, and iterating over the entries can result in the key-value pairs being returned in random order.

The specifics go a bit deeper, though, and there are implementation details to consider. In Dart, `Map` is an abstract class, and there are several different types of `Map` that you can use.

There's the `HashMap` which is the default implementation of `Map`. Insertion order is not preserved, and in fact, the order in which the entries are returned during iteration is fairly random. However, the iteration order only changes when the map itself is changed. This means that as long as you don't add or remove any objects from the map, the iteration order will be the same order every time.

There's also the `LinkedHashMap` class. Unlike the `HashMap`, this type of map *does* preserve insertion order. When you iterate over the entries, they will appear in the same order in which they were added to the map. As such, it is safe to iterate over a `LinkedHashMap` when a particular order is assumed. (Incidentally, this is the type of map created when you use a map literal, i.e. `{ 'a': 1 }`.)

Another example is the `SplayTreeMap`. Unlike the other two, this map maintains a specific order based on the keys' `compareTo` methods. This behavior can also be overridden by passing in a comparison method upon the map's creation.

---

This is all assuming we are talking about iteration order from the `Map`'s perspective. However, looking at it from the perspective of `jsonEncode` can be a different story. Dart delegates to a native platform-specific JSON encoder whenever possible, and that encoder could read maps differently than their implementation would suggest. There's also no real way to predict how the convert library will return a map that was parsed from JSON. This doesn't affect JSON in any way - pretty much every JSON encoder and parser will treat the JSON the same regardless of what order the keys are in.

In short, it's generally not wise to assume that a `Map`'s entries will maintain a predictable or even a consistent order. If you need fixed ordering, another data structure would probably be a better call.